# Как спомощью js нажать сочетание клавиш на клавиатуре?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть кнопка и она имеет событие onclick. По нажатию этой кнопки мне нужно нажимать сочетание клавиш "Ctrl+Z".

```js
function myfunction() {
  //здесь код для того чтобы нажать Ctrl+Z(по клику кнопки нажимать сочетание клавиш)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <mate charset='utf-8'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">Ctrl+Z</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод dispatchEvent в сочетании с объектом KeyboardEvent

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <script>
      function myfunction() {
        // Создание события клавиатуры Ctrl+Z
        var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {ctrlKey: true, key: 'z'});
        
        // Отправка события на текущий элемент (можно изменить на другой элемент, если требуется)
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">Ctrl+Z</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Стоит также упомянуть что `ctrlKey` - пропорция для ОС серии Windows, для Mac нужно обращаться к пропорции `metaKey`. Так что, нужно писать вот так: `{ ctrlKey: true, metaKey: true, key: 'z', keyCode: 122, code: 'KeyZ' }`.